# Mysql, Does the after delete trigger gets executed first before the cascade delete?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables `TABLEA` and `TABLEB`, `TABLEB` has a column `TABLEB.idtablea` which references `TABLEA` column id and I set the `ON DELETE TO CASCADE` in `TABLEB`.

I have two triggers on `TABLEA` `BEFORE DELETE AND AFTER DELETE` which both uses the information store in `TABLEB`.

Do the code of triggers `BEFORE AND AFTER DELETE` get executed before the `CASCADE DELETE` happens?

Comment: My only reaction is that any application that depends on the answer to this question will be very brittle.   This seems like very complicated logic to be setting up in triggers.  Have you considered moving the deletes into stored procedures so you have better control over the processing logic?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I don't use stored procedure because the company that is going to host my website doesn't support stored procedure for shared environment; the other way to go around is removing the foreign constraint and write the delete code manually in the trigger after delete of TABLEA; but I don't wanna do it manual if there is a possibility of automation.

Comment: . . The cascading deletes are a good idea.  They make sense from a relational point of view.  Before and after triggers on the same table in conjunction with cascading deletes seems like a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: The sequence would be `BEFORE DELETE -> CASCADE DELETE -> AFTER DELETE`, so in `AFTER DELETE` you will not have access to the information deleted in `tableB`. See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dnukFQXuzX39fvVsvSRF2X/0).

Comment: @wchiquito why don't you post it as an answer instead of comment?